# Compiling a windows (.exe) executable file using gnu cobol on ubuntu

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, gnucobol

I need a program I wrote in a .cobc file to be compiled to a windows executable file.
The file is called main.cobc 
Compiling it with: cobc -x -free *.cobc -o main 
makes it a linux executable which is ok, but can't be run directly on windows.
I have gnucobol (OpenCOBOL installed on my linux ubuntu VM. 
Please help. Is there a way I could compile it in a way that it's windows compatible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You use an Ubuntu VM on a Windows host, don't you? If you want to compile a program with `cobc` to produce a Windows binary it would likely be much easier to do so on Windows... Please explain what I've missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I could compile it [a COBOL source] in a way that it's windows compatible?

That's not the question that is in the title, so answering that first.
Can you do it from Ubuntu?
Yes, ... as `cobc` uses an underlying C compiler and you can do cross-compiling with C compilers (you'll likely use `gcc-mingw-w64-i686` or `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`).

... but it needs a lot of set-up.

- install the cross-compiler environment
- get all the dependencies for `cobc`/`libcob` working in this environment
- build and install a second version of the GnuCOBOL package from source using `./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32`
- compile your programs using the mingw version of `cobc`

This way you get a "main.exe" which you can use on a Windows computer as long as you ship the mingw dll, libcob dll (and the dll files of all its dependencies).

> I have gnucobol (OpenCOBOL installed on my linux ubuntu VM.
> Please help. Is there a way I could compile it in a way that it's windows compatible?

That's the "long question". Yes, and very easy.
When you do have a Windows environment and want to generate an executable for that - no need for doing this in a separate VM (or WSL) in the first place, just get the official ready-to-use MinGW packages for GnuCOBOL (available for both 32 and 64bit) and compile directly on the Windows machine.

Comment: Instead of a Linux VM, consider WSL for Windows 10.